# We have a new moderator!

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Not a question, but more an announcement. Maybe some of you have already noticed, but we're down to three moderators since Yisela laid down her diamond since yesterday. We want to thank her, lots, for all her work on the site and hope she'll be on as a regular member for a long time to come.

Stack Exchange has told us that, since our most recent election was, well, very recent, we most probably won't be holding a new one. SE will approach the last election's runner-up to see whether they are still interested in the position.

We'll keep you posted as things develop.

---

**Update**: Please join me in welcoming the newest member of the moderator team!

[image: Ryan]

Answer (score 16):

**Thank you for an amazing time!**

These four years have been absolutely awesome, but it's time to move on and let some new blood in. I can't believe that small beta is now a buzzing site and a reference for graphic design. Through this site I met some pretty amazing people I will always treasure.

I'll stick around as a normal civilian, and try my hardest to beat Scott's rep ;) So worry not, I am not gone (or worry yes, I guess).

Thanks again for making GD.SE such a special place!

Comment: Slacker! Glad things are at a point where you don't have as much time for GD.SE Yisela! It can only mean good things!

Comment: TY Yisela, well done. <3

Answer (score 8):

Yisela will always be the queen of GD.SE in my book!!  Glad everything is working out for her and she will be missed.

Comment: queen? dark dictatrix! :P

Answer (score 5):

Congrats @Ryan! Who says there's no reward for second place :) You'll need to hurry to 10k rep now :)

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations @Ryan! I'm very pleased to hear of your promotion.

Comment: Thank you. I will do my best.